# timing loading of clojure source files

Tags: clojure

I want to do some timings of how quickly clojure files load.
Is there a way to hook into the loader to get this information?

I would like to obtain information like this:

```
ie. A depends on B depends on C

A -> starting to load at T(a0)
B -> starting to load at T(b0)
C -> starting to load at T(c0)
C -> loaded at T(c1), time taken 50ms
B -> loaded at T(b1), time taken 100ms
A -> loaded at T(a1), time taken 200ms
```

Comment: Mount works out dependencies by namespace loading, so you could looks at its source code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could replace `clojure.core/load-lib` (or a similar function like `load-one` or `load`) with a wrapping function that logs/times each invocation:

```
(alter-var-root
  #'clojure.core/load-lib
  (fn [f]
    (fn [prefix lib & options]
      (println lib "loading...")
      (let [start (System/nanoTime)
            result (apply f prefix lib options)
            elapsed (double (/ (- (System/nanoTime) start) 1000000))]
        (println lib "loaded in" elapsed "ms")
        result))))
```

Then whenever you load a file with a `ns` declaration, or use `require`/`use`, etc., you'll see output like this:

```
(require 'clojure.spec.test.alpha)
clojure.spec.test.alpha loading...
clojure.pprint loading...
clojure.pprint loaded in 0.159361 ms
clojure.spec.alpha loading...
clojure.spec.alpha loaded in 0.108056 ms
clojure.spec.gen.alpha loading...
clojure.spec.gen.alpha loaded in 0.116731 ms
clojure.string loading...
clojure.string loaded in 0.241387 ms
clojure.spec.test.alpha loaded in 103.37399 ms
=> nil
```

[clojure.tools.namespace](https://github.com/clojure/tools.namespace) might also have some useful functionality for this.